# Dask nested JSON to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dask

I have a gigantic, nested JSON file that I need to parse. I'm currently doing it in Pandas, but would like to find out if I can implement it in Dask for speed/scalability.

My current pandas code is:

```
import pandas as pd
json_data = pd.read_json(input_file)
feature_df = json_normalize(json_obj["Features"], 
    record_path=["Cycles","Pools"],
    meta=["FeatureID"])
```

I've gotten as far as the following code in Dask, but I cannot find any more info on how to do this on the interwebs:

```
import dask.bag as db
import json
json_data = db.read_text(input_file).map(json.loads)
```

This returns a dask bag that I need to figure out how to properly parse.

My JSON is structured as follows:

```
{
"FovID":1,
"Features":[
    {
        "FeatureID":"1_166_155",
        "X":166,
        "Y":155,
        "Cycles":[
            {
                "CycleID":31,
                "Pools":[
                    {
                        "PoolID":1,
                        "BC":"1224",
                        "Qual":"999",
                        "Category":"000"
                    },
                    {
                        "PoolID":2,
                        "BC":"0",
                        "Qual":"999",
                        "Category":"000"}
                 }]}
```

**Solution:**
Instead of using a dask bag, I followed @mdurant's advice and read the JSON directly into a dataframe as follows:

```
json_data = dd.read_json(self.input_s6, orient='columns').compute()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could indeed use the bag API to do your work, but it so happens that the dask-dataframe API also has a [read_json](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_json) function which works like the pandas version.

Having used it `read_json`, you will likely want to use [map_partitions](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions) to apply your row-wise further reduction of the resultant dictionaries.

Comment: Good to know! Could you please provide an example of the syntax I would use for my example JSON? Because I'm having a hell of a time.

Comment: Actually, doing the following (and that doesn't include parsing the columns) was slower than loading in the JSON with uJSON and then parsing with pandas json_normalize(). Did I do something wrong? 

`json_data = dd.read_json(self.input_s6, orient='columns').compute()`

Comment: dask only calls functions, so if you have data small enough to fit in memory, and procedures that max out the CPU, you may well just add overhead when all you are doing is materialising the whole thing in the main thread, rather than doing any processing.